# Lover definition in British English

Tags: word-meaning, british-english, slang

If a person I’ve been seeing calls me ‘my lover’, does it mean that we are more than just dates like calling someone ‘darling’ including romance or is it just dating including sexual intimacy but not romantically? Secondly, what’s the difference between  ‘my lover’ and ‘my love’. I’m trying to understand the boundaries of the term lover. I checked up dictionaries but it might differ in slangs or real life

Comment: You might find this interesting [Here’s Some West Country Regional Slang My Lover!](https://mgm-cs.com/2015/11/22/west-country-regional-slang/) *Around here when you talk to real locals and not the recent arrivals coming as overspill from some of the big cities, you’ll find that practically everyone calls everyone “my love”, “my lover”, “my darling”.*

Comment: That said, it seems odd that you wouldn’t know what kind of relationship you have with someone. Are you trying to figure out if they’re using it incorrectly, or if they’re giving other people the wrong impression of your relationship?

Comment: I’m curious to find what it means when this comes from someone you date. So I don’t think this would be a friendly term said to ordinary people. But when I check dictionaries, I see it’s more like a sexual relationship term

Comment: I don’t understand. Would you edit your question to give an example of a conversation where you would like to understand its meaning? For example, Joe is dating Pat and Pat says …

Comment: Actually it’s clear in the question. Joe is dating Pat and Pat messages Joe “Morning, my lover”. So I’m trying to understand how it differs from “Morning, my love” message. 2 answers below mentioned that if someone uses the term “lover” then it’s more like a sexual relationship and romance is not known to be involved or not

Answer (score 3):

If someone calls you (addresses you) as 'my lover', or 'my love', e.g. 'hello my lover' then it is possible that that they are just being friendly. Where I live (West of England) it is a friendly greeting often used by shop workers etc. Also 'my babe', my darling', (and years ago, 'my little dove'), etc. In the Midlands I am often called 'my duck'.

If someone calls you (describes you to someone else) 'my lover', e.g. 'My lover, Melih, is here tonight', they usually mean that they and you are having a sexual relationship. It implies nothing about whether the relationship is 'romantic' or not.

There is no convention or automatic assumption that a person addressing you as 'my lover', e.g. in a cell phone text message, wishes you to understand that he or she wishes to have sex with you, or they already have had sex with you, that they regard the relationship as romantic or just sexual. There is no substitute for face-to-face conversation, or 'waiting and seeing', to resolve this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

Jack O'Flaherty is right, it would be **extremely** unusual to directly address someone as "my lover" in English. The term would be used to describe someone to a third party and it indicates a sexual relationship; whether there is also a romantic attachment or not is left open.

"My love," on the other hand, is a common term of endearment used between people. It would usually be used between a couple (married or romantically involved; I often address my wife like this), possibly between a parent and a small child (or maybe not so small).

Finally, the use of "love" as a general term of address is common in parts of the UK (as Michael mentioned above), slightly less so in Ireland (where I come from). For example "Can I help you, love?" as said by a shopkeeper to a waiting customer.  However, it is most often used by men addressing women and is falling out of fashion as being somewhat sexist.

Answer (score 2):

In British English, a "lover" is exactly what it means in most other forms of English - it is a term for someone with whom you are in a romantic relationship (eg "they are lovers") but also a term for someone in an *illicit* relationship such as an extra-marital affair (eg "he has a wife but also a lover").

However - "my lover" is used in one specific region of England, the 'West Country' (a loosely defined area of south-western England encompassing Cornwall, Devon, Dorset, Somerset, and sometimes other surrounding areas, too), as an affectionate term for almost anyone, in much the same way that other English people say "my love". Although its meaning and use seems restricted to this region's dialect, it is so widely known that most people in the UK are aware of it, and it is frequently mimicked along with the accompanying accent.

Comment: The other two answers mention that you refer to someone as my lover if you are in a sexual relationship irrespective of romance getting involved. So what you say is another perspective to it. So is it more a sexual term than a romantic term? If someone messages you - let’s say - “Morning, my lover”, how would it differ from “Morning, my love”?

Answer (score -1):

You should ask her/him what they mean by that. It's not common to use "my lover" as a term of address, so there's no established meaning.

Comment: Are you taking into account that the question is about British English? I’m sure calling someone “sug’” or “sugar”  is rare in London, but it is quite common in the Southern US.